# How to fork, create branch and jupyter notebook?

Tags: git, github, jupyter-notebook, gitlab

Hi I am new to the github and jupyter. I want to do couple of task:
a) fork the respo of github.
b) create a branch.
c) create a new jupyter notebook.

a) I went to the desire respo and forked the respo that i needed and clone it using the git CLI. Next step I did was `git remote add upstream` the respo which I cloned. Now after that I am not sure how can I create branch using CLI and then create new jupyter notebook.

**Update:**
I am trying to create a branch as:
`git branch aa-coding` but there is an error.
`fatal: Not a valid object name: 'deafrica-coding'.`

Answer (score 1):

After cloning, you can just do `git checkout -b aa-coding` to create and go to your branch `aa-coding`. Then just edit files and do `git add`, `git commit` and `git push`.

Since you're using Jupyter: The notebook stores the output of each cell within the same file. If you're output exceeds 100MB, you are not allowed to push it to github. Then you can either use git lfs or [remove the output from your notebook](https://zhauniarovich.com/post/2020/2020-06-clearing-jupyter-output/).

Concerning reproducibility: Add your Dockerfiles, requirements.txt, conda yamls and so on to your repo so you can track the versions of the tools you used.

Comment: Thanks danoloo for the details. Now finally I need to push the notebook to the fork. Can you please add the details for that.

Comment: There is also good Jupyter notebook support in VS Code which integrates git in its [GUI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TUYt4oXLxQs). Pushing itself is described [here](https://devconnected.com/how-to-push-git-branch-to-remote/)